# Applying condition using Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

Can we apply a condition on excel?

I need "Remaining Issues" as 0 if "Fixed" is True and "Remaining Issues" as 1 if "Fixed" is False.

[image: Kindly refer this image attached]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply with an `If(` statement like so:

```
=IF(E2,0,1)
```

Since the contents of E2 is a boolean value, just using it like `IF(E2,` will work. But if it is stored as text, use this formula instead:

```
=IF(D1="FALSE",1,IF(D1="TRUE",0,"Error"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case just put below formula to `F2` cell to convert Boolean to numeric.

```
=--C2
```